# Module classes not visible in Minitest describe

Tags: ruby, include, minitest

When I want to include a module into a Minitest/spec test, I can access the functions from the module, but not the classes defined in it. Example:

```rb
module Foo
  def do_stuff
  end
  class Bar
  end
end

x=describe Foo do
  include Foo
end
p x.constants # shows :Bar

describe Foo do
  include Foo
  it "foos" do
    do_stuff # works
    Bar.new # raises a NameError
  end
end
```

Running this snippet gives me a "NameError: uninitialized constant Bar", however, the `p x.constants`shows that `Bar` is defined. I looked into the Minitest source code for `describe` and it uses `class_eval` on the block in the context of some anonymous class. When I do that in the context of a normal class it works fine and I can access `Bar`. Why doesn't it work with `describe/it` or what do I have to do in order to access the classes directly?

EDIT:
Interestingly, if you call `class_eval` directly on some class the included class `Bar` *can* be found, e.g.

```rb
class Quux
  def it_foos
    do_stuff # works
    Bar.new # does NOT raise a NameError
  end
end
Quux.class_eval do
  include Foo
end
Quux.new.it_foos
```

won't throw a `NameError`...

Comment: Can you use `Foo::Bar.new`?

Comment: Sure, but I don't want that. That's why I have the `include` here...

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation for `#class_eval` (for example, https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) you will see the answer there: "Evaluates the string or block in the context of mod, **except that when a block is given, constant/class variable lookup is not affected**".

So, include within `class_eval` simply doesn't affect constants resolution.

As far as I understand from the short look at minitest's source code, `describe` internally creates a new anonymous class (let's name it `C`) and casts class_eval on it with the block you provide. During this call `it`s create the respective test instance methods that are executed later. But `include` doesn't affect constants resolution for `C`, so `Bar` stays unknown.

There is an obvious (and quite ugly) solution - the following should work because you include `Foo` into outer context, so Bar goes into lexical scope accessible for `describe`:

```
include Foo

describe Foo do
  it "foos" do
    do_stuff
    Bar.new
  end
end
```

But tbh I'd avoid such code. Probably it's better to set up the class mock explicitly, smth like

```
module Foo
  def do_stuff
    "foo"
  end

  class Bar
    def do_stuff
      "bar"
    end
  end
end

...

describe Foo do
  let(:cls) { Class.new }

  before { cls.include(Foo) }

  it "foos" do
    assert cls.new.do_stuff == "foo"
  end

  it "bars" do
    assert cls::Bar.new.do_stuff == "bar"
  end
end
```

(but take pls the latter with a grain of salt - I almost never use Minitest so have no idea of its "common idioms")

Comment: Your correct concerning the documentation, but in the context of a normal class it *does* work (despite what the docs say...)

Comment: Hmm, you're right. It does work in your example - when you first define a class and then include a module in class_eval (I'm going to go back and read the docs once again - what do they mean there :)). But. If you try to do `Quux = Class.new.class_eval do...` and do all the stuff (include Foo and then define method(s)) within the single block, e.g. to use exactly the same (but simplified) logic that is implemented within Minitest - it will NOT work (the same NameError). I'd say this constant resolution magic is quite tricky sometimes :)