# Why class_eval evaluates the string and block differently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I am new to ruby and today I found some different behaviour of `class_eval` for string and block. For example

```
class A
end

class C
  A.class_eval("print Module.nesting") # [A, C]
  A.class_eval{print Module.nesting} # [C]
end
```

As you can see in the case of the string `Module.nesting` prints [A,C], while in the case of block it prints only C.

Could you please tell me the reason for this?

Comment: It's in the docs: "when a block is given, constant/class variable lookup is not affected" (https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/class_eval). If this is not clear (it's not for me) I'd suggest updating your question to find out what that actually means in this context.

Comment: Got it. thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module classes not visible in Minitest describe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289791/module-classes-not-visible-in-minitest-describe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you stuff a string into `class_eval`, and this class_eval is invoked on the class A. Hence, when the expression is evaluated, `Module.nesting` - which needs produce its nesting levels - finds itself inside an `A`, which in turn is evaluated inside a `C`.

In the second case, you pass a block, which is similar to a proc object. The effect is comparable to have a

```
 class C
   p = Proc.new { print Module.nesting }
   do_something(p)
 end
```

The Proc represents a *closure*, i.e. the context is that of creating the Proc. It is clear, that the *nesting* here is only C, and this does not change, if you evaluate p inside `do_something`.

This is a good thing. Imagine the following situation:

```
def f(p)
  x = 'f'
  p.call
end

def g
  x = 'g'
  p = Proc.new { puts x }
  f(p)
end
```

Because the binding for p occurs inside method g, the x referenced in the block refers to the local value `x` inside `g`, although `f` has a local variable of the same name. Hence, *g* is printed here. In the same way, the nesting at the point of block definition is reproduced in your example.